# ImportError: cannot import name Ward

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have successfully installed `scikit-learn` version 0.18 but still I'm getting following error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/max/PycharmProjects/LoadForecasting/src/clustering.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/max/PycharmProjects/LoadForecasting/src/clustering.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import Ward
ImportError: cannot import name Ward
```

Comment: Are you following any tutorial? Then should post it here, so that we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the version 0.18, there is no class called `Ward`. You can see all the available classes for `sklearn.cluster` [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cluster). But there is a function called [`ward_tree`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.ward_tree.html#sklearn.cluster.ward_tree) with signature:

```
ward_tree(X, connectivity=None, n_clusters=None, return_distance=False)
```

Hope this is what you want.

If not, then last version in which the class `Ward` was available was 0.16. You can install that specific version of scikit by using:

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.16
```